# What would be the reason for a registration page to hangs after submit?

Tags: users

For some reason whenever i try to submit a new user registration (on a fresh drupal 7 install), the data is correctly sent to the Back end but the page doesn't seem to redirect to the intended location (by default the home page)but instead seems to endlessly submit.

I am pretty sure this come from my testing server as it does it even on a fresh drupal install.
Is there anything that would come to your minds on what could be the cause of this problem ?
We are using ubuntu server with all latest software updates.

Comment: Thank you guys for your input , how ever i tried it all and none of these seems to have fixed out issue, We are going to re install the whole server from scratch and see.. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal uses a lot of files so make sure the real_path_cache in php.ini is increased dramatically.

> max_execution_time to around 120
>
> realpath_cache_size to 512K, 1M or
>   even 2M.
>
> max_input_time to around 120.

Comment: Thank you guys for your input , how ever i tried it all and none of these seems to have fixed out issue, We are going to re install the whole server from scratch and see..

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Check `memory_limit` for your Drupal instance.

On `settings.php` add this line

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
```